# python open error return"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "

Tags: python, windows, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

Recently I met a very odd bug when working with a [crawler](https://github.com/Freddy930727/sukebei-crawler-v2/tree/master/div).
My script works well on almost every case. However, when I tried to execute stress testing(like crawling  1000 set of data)most of the data that I save as `.torrent` works without error, but one of which returns error.
Here is the script.

```
temp=torrent_title
temp=temp[0:246:1]#maximum length of file name in win10
for tempa in range(len(temp)):
    if(temp[tempa] in '\/:*?"<>|'):#special word that can't be named the name of a file in win10
        temp=temp.replace(temp[tempa]," ")
r=requests.get(url)                                
filename=temp+".torrent"
while(not r.status_code==requests.codes.ok):
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open(download_path+"\\"+filename, 'wb').write(r.content)
```

and error

```
 line 119, in main
    open(download_path+"\\"+filename, 'wb').write(r.content)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\C147\\Downloads\\sukebei-crawler-v2-master\\sukebei-crawler-v2-master\\div\\downloads\\08-04-2021_16-35-09\\+++ [HD] 459TEN-016 【性獣危険】Fカップ現役女子大生の自宅に突撃！！とっておきの勝負下着で悩殺ファック！！『人類みなセフレ』！！触れる者みなSEXするとんでもない性獣を捕まえてしまいました！！完全にコントロール不可能のバーサーカービッチにデカチン3人を投入して無限絶頂させまくる！！！イラマと無限ピストンで快楽のその向こう側へ…【性豪ギャル自宅中出し】勝負下着、見せちゃいます！vol.13.torrent'
```

By the way,this script is execute on win10.

Comment: Could you write assertions to check that paths/files exist? Also, maybe use cleaner filenames?

Comment: Hello,this program works well on most cases(In other case  i save .torrent in the same folder),so i think the problem may related to file name.Thank you.

Comment: Yes, so assert that file exists. As is, the filename is too long and may have "encoding" issues due to things like spaces.

Comment: Windows is notorious for icky weirdness around complex file names. Perhaps try to run the stress test on a platform which supports arbitrary file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer by myself.
Just add encoding=‘utf-8-sig ’ to open() ,then it can work fine on win10.